# Xmpp + openfire + server acknowledgement to the sender

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, smack

I'm developing IM application.
I want to get acknowledgement at the time of

**when message is received by the Openfire server**

I have used below gradles

```
//XMPP Gradles
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.0'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.0'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.1.0'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-extensions:4.1.0'
```

**Note**: I have already gone through each and every StackOverflow links and conclude that Openfire doesn't support **XEP-0184**, and it describes a mechanism for **delivery** receipts only.

I have also tried **DeliveryReceiptManager** and set their **addReceiptReceivedListener** but its not working.

Any workarounds or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: put `DeliveryReceiptManager.getInstanceFor(connection).enableAutoReceipts();`  after successful connection

Comment: Let me try @Maddy.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to attach a common listener to every sent message and update your database(and hence your UI) accordingly.

Define a random UUID for each outgoing message:

```
String stanzaId = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
```

Attach the listener to your message:

```
xmppTcpConnection.addStanzaIdAcknowledgedListener(stanzaId , new StanzaListener()
{
    @Override
    public void processStanza(Stanza packet) throws SmackException.NotConnectedException, InterruptedException
    {
     // You can match your stanzaId here!
     // packet.getStanzaId()   
    }
});
```

add:

```
compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.2.0"
```

to get `XMPPTCPConnection` object.

**Update:** Try adding the listener before calling `connect()` on the `xmppTcpConnection` object.

Comment: not getting you @Sarthak , did this addStanzaIdAcknowledgedListener ,gives us acknowledgement of sender's message from server side (ex: this message is received by server)?

Comment: I'm also facing message skipping issue! any work around for that?

Comment: @Radhey yes when you get a callback in your `processStanza` method, it means that the particular message was successfully received by the server.

Comment: @Radhey message skipping as in?

Comment: I have used AbstractXMPPConnection object rather than xmppTcpConnection and there is not any addStanzaIdAcknowledgedListener methods there!

Comment: Let's discuss in chat room @Sarthak.

Comment: sure, where?
btw, I have updated the answer, just add the import and you will have access to XMPPTCPConnection

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153012/discussion-between-radhey-and-sarthak-mittal).

Comment: Thanks @Sarthak but still it didn't work. So I can't accept it as exact answer.If I will get work around with your suggestions then surely I will except it.

Comment: @Radhey sure! callback ain't getting invoked?

Comment: Nope brother! not getting any callback.

Comment: Thank you @SarthakMittal , you saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

while sending message attach `DeliveryReceiptRequest.addTo(msg);`

like this

```
Message msg = new Message(oppositeUserId, Message.Type.chat);
msg.setBody(mMessageBody);
msg.setStanzaId(messageId);
msg.setFrom(loginUserId);

DeliveryReceiptRequest.addTo(msg);

mXMPPTCPConnection.sendStanza(msg);
```

> XmppDeliveryReceiptManager.java

```
public class XmppDeliveryReceiptManager implements ReceiptReceivedListener {


    private static final String TAG = XmppDeliveryReceiptManager.class.getSimpleName();

    Context mContext;


    public XmppDeliveryReceiptManager(Context mContext) {
       this.mContext = mContext;
       Log.d(TAG, "XmppDeliveryReceiptManager : initialized ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiptReceived(String fromJid, String toJid, String receiptId, Stanza receipt) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceiptReceived : receiptId = " + receiptId);
        // do need full with "receiptId"         
    }
}
```

add this to your XMPP configuration

```
/*  Add XMPP DeliveryReceiptManager */
ProviderManager.addExtensionProvider(DeliveryReceipt.ELEMENT,
            DeliveryReceipt.NAMESPACE, new DeliveryReceipt.Provider());
ProviderManager.addExtensionProvider(DeliveryReceiptRequest.ELEMENT,
            new DeliveryReceiptRequest().getNamespace(), new DeliveryReceiptRequest.Provider());

mXmppDeliveryReceiptManager = new XmppDeliveryReceiptManager(mContext);
mDeliveryReceiptManager = DeliveryReceiptManager.getInstanceFor(mXMPPTCPConnection);
mDeliveryReceiptManager.setAutoReceiptMode(DeliveryReceiptManager.AutoReceiptMode.always);
        mDeliveryReceiptManager.addReceiptReceivedListener(mXmppDeliveryReceiptManager);
```

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for!